# Combobox to integer Value @ Runtime To change FontSize

Tags: vb.net, combobox, int, font-size

i am trying to be able to change the font size with a combobox.
problem is that @runtime i get a  error there is no value.
on form load i am Setting selectedindexitem to 3

MyCode:

UPDATE: Only works if i set the integer value with a number... I wish to be able to change it with comboboox1.

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2
    End Sub

     Dim myFontSize As Integer = 120
    Dim myFont As New Font("Arial", myFontSize, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
    Dim Loc As Point
    Dim Pxy As Point

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        txtButton.Text = MouseButtons.Left
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Loc = e.Location
            Me.PictureBox1.Invalidate()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint


        Dim pt As Point = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtA.Text, myFont, Brushes.Black, pt.X, pt.Y)
    End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyPress
        Dim KeyAscii As Integer = Asc(e.KeyChar)
        Select Case KeyAscii
            Case 8, 27, 48 To 57, 9
            Case Else
                KeyAscii = 0
        End Select
        If KeyAscii = 0 Then
            e.Handled = True
        Else
            e.Handled = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

Maybe not important but i have  code on Combobox_KeyPress to Only allow numbers.any help or point ,me in right dirrection?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood good, the problem is that on your form load event it throws an exception because there is no selected item in the combobox?.

Also, where are you trying to run that code?.

Anyways you could write a conditional to ensure that there is a selected item then avoid that exception:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)

    If cb.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then

        Using font As New Font("Arial", Convert.ToInt32(cb.Text),
                               FontStyle.Bold Or 
                               FontStyle.Italic)

            otherControl.Font = font

        End Using

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply @ElektroStudios but it allows the app to start but has no change on fontsize , here is the rest of the code how i have it and how it works. i simply want to be able to channge the fontsize with ComboBox1.

Answer (score 0):

I got it Working!

```
Dim myFontSize As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(ComboBox1.Text, myFontSize)
        Dim myFont As New Font("Arial", myFontSize, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
```

this did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You should get the `FontSize` from the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` and not from the parent. Also "FontSize" is already a variable in strings so you should name your custom variable something else:

```
Dim MyFontSize As Integer = CInt(myComboBox.SelectedItem)
Dim myFont As New Font("Arial", MyFontSize, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
```

Comment: Sorry but i downvote because both things said in your answer are not true.